# SUPEE 11219 Error "Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!"

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I've tried installing this patch on my Magento (1.9.4.3), I'm not sure what to do, here is the full message:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
4 out of 4 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.2-1.6.1.3.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Api/User/Edit/Tab/Main.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Set/Main.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Renderer/Newpass.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Queue/Preview.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Comment: as per your message, it seems patch already applied. you can verify it from `app/etc/applied.patches.list` file.

Comment: Weird, the file does not exist in the "app/etc" path.

Comment: if file not exist that means previous patch was not applied by SSH.maybe direct file replaced!